# UTF8 encoding error while posting request after adding boundaries to original file content

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I am trying to read a file, add boundaries around it and post it to my url.
I tried to read file, decode (using `latin1` as `utf-8` was not working) and concatenate boundary strings, save this file with `utf-8` encoding.
All these work fine.

But when i tried to post this file it gave me an error ***"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 23: invalid start byte"*** - How do I solve this problem? Is there a way to post other encodings than `utf-8` in requests?

```
gen_data = open(fw_file,'rb').read()
boundary = '------WebKitFormBoundaryV2I0Y3IdM8aQPLv3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'\
           + file_name + '"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n'
boundary_end = '\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryV2I0Y3IdM8aQPLv3--\r\n'

def create_data(boundary, data, end):
    return boundary + data.decode('latin1') + end

data = create_data(boundary, gen_data, boundary_end)
export_file = rf'c:\temp\{file_name}'
open(export_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8").write(data)
resp = requests.post(target, files=export_file, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Following is the exception log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 515, in request
        prep = self.prepare_request(req)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 443, in prepare_request
        p.prepare(
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 321, in prepare
        self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 514, in prepare_body
        (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 128, in _encode_files
        files = to_key_val_list(files or {})
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 343, in to_key_val_list
        raise ValueError('cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples')
    ValueError: cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples
    python-BaseException
```

***EDIT***
I tried to upload data directly using following code:
`resp = requests.post(target, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)`

But got following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1372, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 289, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1372, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 289, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
python-BaseException
```

Comment: using codecs? import codecs

Comment: Nothing solved the problem as of now - i had to switch to http_client